# SQL Error(1054): Unknown column in 'where clause' when trying to update. Column is actually available

Tags: mariadb-10.1

I have two tables namely table_a and table_b.

Table_a has several columns including student_id and course_start_date
Table_b has several columns including student_id and fee_pay_date
student_id is INT field and course_start_date & fee_pay_date are DATE fields

I want to update column course_start_date in table_a by reading fee_pay_date from table_b for each student.

When I write the following command in MariadB, it throws up an error:

```
UPDATE table_a 
SET table_a.course_start_date = table_b.fee_pay_date 
WHERE (table_a.student_id = table_b.student_id);

Error: SQL Error(1054): Unknown column 'table_b.student_id in 'where clause'
```

I have checked the tables. All column names are correct. Can anyone help on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That is not valid SQL - you are not referencing table_b in any `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses so can not use columns from it in `SELECT`, `SET`, `WHERE` or other parts.

Sticking to standards compliant SQL you need to use a sub-select here:

```
UPDATE table_a 
   SET table_a.course_start_date = (
           SELECT table_b.fee_pay_date
             FROM table_b
            WHERE table_b.student_id = table_a.student_id
            );
```

Some databases support using `JOIN`s in `UPDATE` statements so avoid sub-selects. This can often be easier to read but will break if you need to support different database back-ends. For mySQL and MariaDB this would be something like:

```
UPDATE table_a 
  JOIN table_b 
       ON (table_a.student_id = table_b.student_id)
   SET table_a.course_start_date = table_b.fee_pay_date
       ;
```

Not that both of these statements will update every row in `table_a` even if the row already has the right value so could be very inefficient if only a few rows actually need updating. This is by design, as you might want triggers to fire and so forth even for a NoOp update. To avoid this if it is not desirable add a `WHERE` clause to block unneeded updates:

```
UPDATE table_a 
  JOIN table_b 
       ON table_a.student_id = table_b.student_id
   SET table_a.course_start_date = table_b.fee_pay_date
 WHERE table_a.course_start_date <> table_b.fee_pay_date
    OR (table_a.course_start_date IS     NULL AND table_b.fee_pay_date IS NOT NULL)
    OR (table_a.course_start_date IS NOT NULL AND table_b.fee_pay_date IS     NULL)
       ;
```

or:

```
UPDATE table_a 
  JOIN table_b 
       ON table_a.student_id = table_b.student_id
   SET table_a.course_start_date = table_b.fee_pay_date
 WHERE COALESCE(table_a.course_start_date, '9999-01-01') <> COALESCE(table_b.fee_pay_date, '9999-01-01');
```

<sub>(you can simplify those `WHERE` clauses a bit if `table_b.fee_pay_date` can never be NULL)</sub>

---

---

As a related side-issue: to illustrate the concern of using non-standard syntax, the SQL Server equivalent to

```
UPDATE table_a 
  JOIN table_b 
       ON table_a.student_id = table_b.student_id
   SET table_a.course_start_date = table_b.fee_pay_date
       ;
```

would be

```
UPDATE table_a 
   SET course_start_date = table_b.fee_pay_date
  FROM table_a
  JOIN table_b 
       ON table_a.student_id = table_b.student_id
       ;
```

and in postgres you would need:

```
UPDATE table_a 
   SET course_start_date = table_b.fee_pay_date
  FROM table_b 
 WHERE table_a.student_id = table_b.student_id
       ;
```

Not vastly different, but if you want to support multiple databases or later move from one to another, you need to be careful of this sort of difference. The sub-query version should behave the same in all three (and most other places).

Comment: Thank you very much David for your help. Your solution worked very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Your Update statement is missing a reference to table_b. The statement should be in the form of

```
UPDATE table_a, table_b
SET 
      table_a.course_start_date = table_b.fee_pay_date 
WHERE 
      table_a.student_id = table_b.student_id;
```

The Mariab [Update](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/update/) and [Adding/Changing](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/adding-and-changing-data-in-mariadb/) data documentation provides some good examples.